# render radio button in asp.net mvc using knockout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

my model -

```
public class Model
        {
            public String SelectedValue;
        }
```

action method -

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Model model = new Model();
            model.SelectedValue = "a";
            return View("Index1", model);
        }
```

view -

```
<input type="radio" name="Group1" value="a" data-bind="attr: { checked: SelectedValue }" />
        <input type="radio" name="Group1" value="b" data-bind="attr: { checked: SelectedValue }" />
        <input type="radio" name="Group1" value="c" data-bind="attr: { checked: SelectedValue }" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        var data = @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
        BindData();
</script>
```

My javascript -

```
function BindData() {
    viewModelData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModelData);
}
```

When my view is rendered, it renders all three radio buttons with the one with value = "c" selected. But from action method i am selecting radio button with value "a". why is it so?

Can anyone please help me understanding whether i have any issue with my code or how does knockout handle radio button selections internally. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`checked` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) instead of the `attr` binding which is directly created for this scenario:

> The checked binding links a checkable form control — i.e., a checkbox (`<input type='checkbox'>`) or a radio button (`<input type='radio'>`) — with a property on your view model.

So in your case you need to write:

```
<input type="radio" name="Group1" value="a" data-bind="checked: SelectedValue" />
<input type="radio" name="Group1" value="b" data-bind="checked: SelectedValue" />
<input type="radio" name="Group1" value="c" data-bind="checked: SelectedValue" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LkFG/).